# How can a group by query be used to get the number of occurences of a particular column?

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to get the results in a way that each order is displayed with the number of times they occur in a table. For example:

```
Chicken Parmessan - 3
Polo Pizza        - 5
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select food, count(*) from tablename group by food
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table like this:

```
create table orders (
    menu_item varchar(100) not null
)
```

Then you'd want something like this:

```
select menu_item, count(*)
from orders
group by menu_item
```

The aggregate function `count` will then count the number of entries in each group and each group will be identified by `menu_item`.